# Laravel Gate::before SuperAdmin create doesn't work

Tags: laravel, flask-superadmin

Using gate::before in Authserviceprovider into boot function like below

```
Gate::before(function (Admin $user, $ability) {
                          if ($user->isSuperAdmin('Super-admin')){
                                 return true;
                                }
                            });
```

then giving definition isSuperAdmin() method in Admin Model like below

```
public function isSuperAdmin($ability){
                              foreach (\auth()->user()->roles as $role){
                               foreach ($role->permissions as $permission){
                                  return $permission->name == $ability;}}}
```

but superAdmin still restricted

Comment: SuperAdmin should be a role, not as permission.

Answer (score 2):

```
 Gate::before(function (Admin $user, $ability) {
        return $user->hasRole('Super-admin') ? true : null;
    });
```

I think this will be enough. No need foreachs, permission checks, extra functions.